# PHP stream socket not working with HTML5 socket?

Tags: javascript, php, html, sockets

It seems that most HTML5 web socket example online with PHP are using the socket plugin. Is it possible to use `stream_socket_server` with HTML5 web socket?

If yes, I am trying to build a simple socket server + client with PHP `stream_socket_server` function. Here is the code:

PHP socket server:

```php
<?php   
$server = stream_socket_server("tcp://localhost:8080", $errno, $errorMessage);

if ($server === false) {
    throw new UnexpectedValueException("Could not bind to socket: $errorMessage");
}

for (;;) {
    $client = stream_socket_accept($server);

    if ($client) {
        echo 'Connection accepted from '.stream_socket_get_name($client, false) . "\n";
        stream_copy_to_stream($client, $client);
    }
}
```

HTML5 Web Socket Client.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Client Testing</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="send">Testing button</button>
    <script>
        websocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080");
        websocket.onopen = function(evt) { /* do stuff */ }; //on open event
        websocket.onclose = function(evt) { /* do stuff */ }; //on close event
        websocket.onmessage = function(evt) { /* do stuff */ }; //on message event
        websocket.onerror = function(evt) { /* do stuff */ }; //on error event
        $('#send').click( function(){
            websocket.send("This is a testing message"); //send method
        });
        //websocket.close(); //close method
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the return when I am connecting:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: net::ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE
```

What have I missed? How do I return a valid HTTP response?

Comment: it's better to stick with open source tested libraries, you are not following the Websocket RFC at all.

Answer (score 2):

You get this error `ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE` because you don't send the appripriate response through your socket.

A response from the server to the client looks like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: s3pPLMBiTxaQ9kYGzzhZRbK+xOo=
Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: chat
```

So you need to write that to the socket:

```
socket_write($accept, $httpResponse);
```

You also need to implement polling via `socket_select()`, currently your program is not able to handle more than a single connection.

Also don't forget to use `socket_close()` when you're done.

---

**Old Answer**

A generic socket is opened upon OSI layer 4. You open a UNIX socket, a TCP socket, a UDP socket.

It is also possible to open sockets on lower OSI layers like for ICMP or even IP which are generally called "raw sockets".

A Websocket is an Application layer protocol - OSI layer 7. A Websocket uses a generic socket (single duplex TCP connection) to send and receive its data.

You cannot connect one to the other without further implementation. A Websocket is build upon a normal socket.

See:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket

Comment: So, how to run php stream socket with javascript WebSocket?